Issue with signature-v4-crt package in NextJS
I have the below code that works perfectly fine in a simple nodejs app.
// index.js
const {
    CloudFrontKeyValueStoreClient,
    DescribeKeyValueStoreCommand, PutKeyCommand, ListKeysCommand
  } = require("@aws-sdk/client-cloudfront-keyvaluestore");
  
  require("@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt");
  
  (async () => {
    try {
      // Initialize the CloudFront KeyValueStore Client
      const client = new CloudFrontKeyValueStoreClient({
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: 'XXX',
          secretAccessKey: 'XXX',
        },
      });
  
      const input = {
        KvsARN: "arn:aws:cloudfront::xxx:key-value-store/xxx-xxx-xxx",
      };
  
      // Create a new command
      const command = new DescribeKeyValueStoreCommand(input);
  
      // Send the command to the client
      const response = await client.send(command);
  
      // Log the response
      console.log(response);


      const input1 = { // PutKeyRequest
        Key: "sports", // required
        Value: "true", // required
        KvsARN: "arn:aws:cloudfront::xxx:key-value-store/xxx-xxx-xxx", // required
        IfMatch: response.ETag // required
      };
      const command1 = new PutKeyCommand(input1);
      const response1 = await client.send(command1);
      console.log('response 1: ', response1);

    } catch (e) {
      // Catch and log any errors
      console.error("Error:", e);
    }
  })();
  

However, if I use it inside a NextJS app route, it doesn't work:
// index.js
const {
    CloudFrontKeyValueStoreClient,
    DescribeKeyValueStoreCommand, PutKeyCommand, ListKeysCommand
  } = require("@aws-sdk/client-cloudfront-keyvaluestore");
  
  require("@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt");

//export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'; // Opt out of static generation

export async function GET() {
  try {
    // Initialize the CloudFront KeyValueStore Client
    const client = new CloudFrontKeyValueStoreClient({
        region: 'eu-west-1',
        credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'XXX',
        secretAccessKey: 'XXX',
        },
    });

    // Input for the DescribeKeyValueStoreCommand
    const input = {
        KvsARN: "arn:aws:cloudfront::xxx:key-value-store/xxx-xxx-xxx", // Replace with your own ARN
    };

    // Create a new command
    const command = new DescribeKeyValueStoreCommand(input);

    // Send the command to the client
    const response = await client.send(command);

    // Log the response
    console.log(response);

    const input1 = { // PutKeyRequest
        Key: "sports", // required
        Value: "true", // required
        KvsARN: "arn:aws:cloudfront::xxx:key-value-store/xxx-xxx-xxx", // required
        IfMatch: response.ETag // required
    };
    const command1 = new PutKeyCommand(input1);
    const response1 = await client.send(command1);
    console.log('response 1: ', response1);

    return Response.json(response1 );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return Response.json({ error: 'An error occurred' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

The error I'm getting is this:

Please check whether you have installed the
"@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt" package explicitly.  You must also
register the package by calling
[require("@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt");] or an ESM equivalent such as
[import "@aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt";].  For more information please go
to
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3#functionality-requiring-aws-common-runtime-crt

I have installed @aws-sdk/signature-v4-crt and also imported the package in both nodejs app and nextjs app. Everything works fine on nodejs app. But it fails with this error in nextjs app.
